# Changing style inside Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, findcontrol

I have a problem changing the style of my UserName TextBox inside of asp:Login.
It seems like my code never actually finds the textbox because the style dosen't change at all. 
Following code example:

```
<asp:Login ID="myLogin" runat="server" OnLoginError="myLogin_LoginError">
    <LayoutTemplate>
         <div class="append-icon">
             <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-white username" placeholder="Username"></asp:TextBox>
             <i class="icon-user"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="append-icon m-b-20">
             <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control form-white password" placeholder="Password" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
             <i class="icon-lock"></i>
         </div>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Login" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-dark btn-rounded" Text="Sign in" ValidationGroup="login">
             <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Login
         </asp:LinkButton>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>

protected void myLogin_LoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)myLogin.FindControl("UserName");
    tb.Attributes.Add("style", "form-control form-white username form-error");
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be `tb.Attributes.Add("class".....` ? Also when debugging what is the value of `tb` at run time?

Comment: `FindControl` finds the textbox. Otherwise the setting of the attribute would trigger an exception. You need to add the new classes to the `CssClass` rather than to the `style`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the style attribute, modify the CssClass attribute like so:

```
protected void myLogin_LoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)myLogin.FindControl("UserName");
    tb.CssClass += " " + "form-error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)myLogin.FindControl("UserName");
tb.CssClass = "form-control form-white username form-error";
```